# Get hash value with out query params in URL?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can we get only hash value without query params using javascript/jquery ?

Problem is,

http://www.somedomain.com/me/terms.html#terms - location.hash.substr(1) - terms

http://www.somedomain.com/me/terms.html#terms?queryParam=1 - location.hash.substr(1) - terms?queryParam=1

we can parse the URL and get the hash value but is there any direct/efficient methods available javascript/jquery ?

Comment: see http://tech-blog.maddyzone.com/javascript/get-current-url-javascript-jquery

Answer (score 2):

The fragment identifier should be AFTER the query string.
From Wikipedia:

> The syntax (for url scheme) is:
>   scheme://domain:port/path?query_string#fragment_id

This is important, as in your example the query string would not reach the server. If you are using a front-end library, you might have access to some APIs that let you access it though. The $location service in AngularJS by default addresses ONLY the part after the first hash (as the hash indicates routing start for the front-end app).
https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/$location

in your case, $location.path() would equal *terms* and $location.search() would equal *queryparam=1*; $location.hash() would be null.

Comment: This is correct way to use the hash. Now im changing backend. Thanks Wiherek.

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way would probably be to use a regex that starts on the hash and ends on the ? or end of string.  Something like this:

/#(.+)\??/gi

First capture group should yield out the contents of the hash.

Comment: Still I'm getting confused - terms.html#terms?param-1 - location.href.match(/#(.+)\??/gi) -  ["#terms?param=1"]

Answer (score 0):

Don't even have to regex. It is already here as part of Javascript with location.hash;

```
Assume that the current URL is http://www.example.com/test.htm#part2:

var x = location.hash;
The result of x will be:

#part2
```

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_loc_hash.asp

Comment: Thanks. But this only works for test.html#part2 not for test.html#part2?queryParamm=1

Comment: Ahh understood, then use Paul's method with regex to pull in the items

Answer (score 0):

```
 test.html#part2?queryParamm=1
```

`window.location.hash` give `#part2`

`window.location.search` give   `?queryParamm=1`

for more see http://tech-blog.maddyzone.com/javascript/get-current-url-javascript-jquery